# Why is R creating a lumpy version of my periodic function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph of the periodic function -23.5*cospi/4(x)+23.5
It gives the results I want in Desmos for reference.

However, when I code it as a function and plot it in ggplot, I get a weird-looking periodic function.

```
 x <- 0:32
    test <- data.frame(x, y=-23.5*cos(pi/4*x)+23.5)
    test2 <- function(x) -23.5*cos(pi/4*x)+23.5
    
    ggplot(data = test, mapping = aes(x,y))+
      geom_point()+
      stat_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

The points show as normal, but the stat_smooth gives this lumpy hunk of garbage.

Comment: stat_smooth defaults to loess, probably not what you want, just do geom_line instead.

Answer (score 2):

As you want to graph a function I would suggest to use `geom_function`:

Note: For smoothness I doubled the default number of interpolation points `n`.

```r
x <- 0:32
test <- data.frame(x, y = -23.5 * cos(pi / 4 * x) + 23.5)
test2 <- function(x) -23.5 * cos(pi / 4 * x) + 23.5

library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = test, mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_function(fun = test2, n = 202)
```

[image]